# How do I make an Object active on key down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity's new input system and I'm trying to set up an input that places a shield in front of you as long as you hold the key down.
At the moment I can make the shield appear in the world but it's fixed in the world and locked to one direction.

[image: Like so]

Right now this is the code.

```
private void ShieldUp() {
    GameObject shield = GameObject.Instantiate(shieldPrefab, playerFront.position, Quaternion.identity, bulletParent);
}
```

I created a prefab for the "shield", playerFront being the location where I want it spawn. I think all I've done is make it so every time I hit the shield key it just makes a prefab.

But, like stated before, I want it to only appear while the key is held and deleted when the key is released.
I'd also want it to face the same direction as the character, but one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Now the problem with the new input system is there so many ways that you can use it.
so to actually help we need a lot more information about how you use the new input system.

about the code you were showing you are instantiated entire new game object each time you click the Shield button, I would recommend using a GameObject that is a child of the player GameObject and simply activating and deactivating it.

I can give you a example with the old input system.

```
public class PlayerShield : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject shield;

    private void Awake()
    {
        shield.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        UseShield();
    }

    private void UseShield()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            shield.SetActive(true);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E))
        {
            shield.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```